# How to provide expression to R from command-line but stop R from immediately exiting?

Tags: r

I know how to start R from the command-line and execute an expression (e.g., `R -e 'print("hello")'`) or take input from a file (e.g., `R -f filename.r`). However, in both cases, R runs the expression or commands in the file and then exits.

- How can I change the above so that R doesn't exit after running the commands in the file or running the expression?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put your script in a file called .Rprofile in the current directory. Then start R normally.

Comment: Thanks. I knew about global .Rprofile settings, but I didn't realise that you could have a directory specific version. Cheers.

Comment: But what if I need to run just one-time command? Then placing it to .Rprofile and deleting it again is clumsy.

Comment: @TomasT. A bit clumsy perhaps, but I know of no other way to both run some script code AND THEN let user continue interactively. It doesn't seem like a common case, so I guess that's why it's a bit clumsy. You could submit a software patch to `r-devel` to address it though ;-)